# SQL Server Management Studio continuously not responding and very slow

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a Lenovo T480s:

- Intel i7 8th Gen
- 16 GB Ram
- Windows 10

The problem is that I get some issues with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17 (is up to date).

When I use SSMS, for example to visualize a database, a table or to edit a table, I continuously get the message

> Not Responding

and it often loses the connection.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably add some configs as well.

Comment: Could you tell more about the general situation?
Do you use a local or a sql server on another machine? Do you are in a LAN, VPN connected or in a cloud (e.g. Azure)? 
Because that sounds more like a network or server problem.

Comment: I use sql server locally and I'm in a LAN. Yes I think that is a server problem but I don't know what's the problem because I bought the pc for work reason and the first thing that I installed was sql server and sql server management, I mean the machine Is new and no other configuration are been applied, I simply downloaded and installed all

Comment: If you've installed a local SQL Server instance, be sure to configure `max server memory` to ensure enough RAM is available to other applications. To configure for 4GB for example: `EXEC  sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;RECONFIGURE`

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dan but it doesn't fix my problem